# Uitableview reload issue when initially it’s empty

Tags: ios, uitableview

Suppose that I have a UITableview that displays messages. Let’s say that initially it’s empty.

Now I write the first message and call for `[tableview reloadData]`. But the message (the very first custom cell) doesn’t show up until I **scroll the tableview down a bit**!!!??? This problem doesn’t exist with the second or any following messages. Only with the first one when tableview is empty.

Here is my layout for tableview:

```
msgList = [[UITableView alloc] init];
msgList.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - MIN(self.view.frame.size.width, 700))/2, grpMsg.frame.size.height+10, MIN(self.view.frame.size.width, 700), self.view.frame.size.height-grpMsg.frame.size.height-10);

msgList.delegate = self;
msgList.dataSource = self;

if (self.view.frame.size.width <= 700) {
    msgList.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
} else {
    msgList.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
[msgList visibleCells];
[msgList indexPathsForVisibleRows];
msgList.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
msgList.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
msgList.keyboardDismissMode  = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
msgList.estimatedRowHeight = 80;
msgList.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(56.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
msgList.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
msgList.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1); // flip tableView upside down
msgList.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0];
[self.view addSubview:msgList];
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you need to set top constraints on tableview,

Comment: can you post your layout setup? if you are using storyboard and autolayout, or your code if you are adding your tableView programatically

Comment: Yes, I did just now.

Comment: can you add NSLog(@"%f", msgList.frame.origin.y) and post what prints? @ekashking

Comment: It prints: 72.500000

Comment: you are using scale as transform, can you test commenting that line?, let me know @ekashking

Comment: Seem like it doesn't get stuck, BUT i need to flip the table to make messages work.

Answer (score 0):

After sending a message, getting new data and calling `[tableView reloadData];` I also have to call for:

> ```
> dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>     msgList.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(MAX(keyboardHeight+12, msgList.frame.size.height - msgList.contentSize.height), 0, 0, 0);
> });
> ```

... to (I guess) refresh the layout. The problem is gone.